how to apply condition in laravel model relation function
I am trying to get a result of query relation using relation methods in Laravel11 model
Department table has a field named parent and it's default value is 0
I write an if statement but it always return the else result
here is my code
class Department extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function members() {
        
        if($this->parent==0)
            return $this->hasManyThrough(
                Profile::class,
                Department::class,
                'parent',
                'department_id'
            );
        else 
            return $this->hasMany(Profile::class,'department_id');
    } 
}


Should your if condition check if the parent attribute is NOT equal to zero? You are checking for zero and then using parent in the relation, but the else part is not using parent

Don't skip {} in an if statement. Use shorthands like return $this->parent ? true : false if you want to skip them. Can you do a return gettype($this->parent) to see what the value actually is? Debugging your code is a primary thing programmers need to do, you should really get used to it instead of asking questions on a value you should know the answer of ;)
